# Losing event handlers and having problems re-adding event handlers after switching layers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following code that I'm using to move an svg group to the front:

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveInFrontOf = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        this[0].parentNode.append(this[0]);
    });
};
```

This effectively raises the layer.  I'm stuck with d3 v3. If I was able to use d3 v4 then I'd use the the new `raise()` function. The event handlers are getting lost and I'm having a hard time adding them back.  Here's the code that I'm using to add a click handler back to a path:

```
d3.select(overlay).on('click', "javascript:alert('test')" );
```

The JS seems to be valid but when I check the path element in the element inspector the click handler doesn't get added.  I think I've read that when group order is changed dynamically with d3, the event handlers get lost.  Is there also an issue with trying to add the event handlers back?  Or is there a special technique that should be used?  Or does something look wrong with my code?  Is there a simpler mod I can make as a first step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using D3 v4 (and the handy `raise()` and `lower()` functions), you'll have to create a workaround. There are different ways of doing this using D3 v3 (some of them very hacky, some of them a little bit more elegant).

This one relies on sorting the DOM array. This way, since you're just sorting the elements in an array, you don't loose any event handler.

In this demo, the event handler is a `mouseover` event that changes the color to red. When you click the circle, you bring it up by sorting the DOM array:

```js
var data = d3.range(4).map(d => ({
  clicked: false
}))

var circles = d3.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data);

circles.on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(this).attr("fill", "red")
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  d3.select(this).attr("fill", "blue")
});

circles.on("click", function() {
  d3.select(this).datum().clicked = true;
  circles.sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(a.clicked, b.clicked)
  });
  d3.select(this).datum().clicked = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height=200>
  <circle cy="100" cx="80" r="60" fill="blue" stroke-width="3" stroke="black"></circle>
  <circle cy="100" cx="160" r="60" fill="blue" stroke-width="3" stroke="black"></circle>
  <circle cy="100" cx="240" r="60" fill="blue" stroke-width="3" stroke="black"></circle>
  <circle cy="100" cx="320" r="60" fill="blue" stroke-width="3" stroke="black"></circle>
</svg>
```